# Removed Sprite Still Clickable

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite

In a menu of my game:

1. There is a box that the user can click. In the first stage, this box just has one 'wizard' sprite in it
2. When either the box or the image is tapped/clicked, the wizard is removed and replaced with 2 buttons, one to go back and one to confirm.
3. I have set this up so I have a variable (beenClicked2) is set to 0 when the box is in stage 1 (or just when the wizard sprite is in it)
4. When the box is pressed, the beenClicked2 variable changes to 1 so that the box cant be clicked again when in stage 2 and doesn't crash.
5. However, when the box only shows the wizard (stage1) the back button from stage 2 is still clickable which means the box doesn't show the 2 buttons and just stays in stage1

Image to show this:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/st5fgv25fp3rz30/Image.png?dl=0

Here is my code:

```
//PURCHASING
        if atPoint(location) == customBack2 || atPoint(location) == twoLivesWizard {
            if lock1 == 0 && beenClicked2 == 0 {
                twoLivesWizard.removeFromParent()
                locked.removeFromParent()
                self.addChild(purchaseText1)
                self.addChild(purchaseTick1)
                self.addChild(purchaseBack1)

                beenClicked2 = 1
                print("\(beenClicked2)")
            }
        }

//Cancel Purchase
        if atPoint(location) == purchaseBack1 {
            beenClicked2 = 0
            self.addChild(locked)
            self.addChild(twoLivesWizard)
            purchaseText1.removeFromParent()
            purchaseTick1.removeFromParent()
            purchaseBack1.removeFromParent()

            print("\(beenClicked2)")
        }
```

Comment: A lack of information here. 1) Which sprite is still clickable ( you mentioned that in your title) ? 2) Try to define "clicking in the wrong place" ? 3) What is the *box* you are talking about ? Try to be more precise when you posting problems. Help people to help you.

Comment: @Whirlwind Hi, sorry for not being clear. I have updated the question. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple workable example, which can probably give you a clue in which direction you might go:

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    private let box = SKSpriteNode(color: .yellow, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 300))

    private let wizard = SKSpriteNode(color: .purple, size: CGSize(width: 150, height: 250))
    private let back = SKSpriteNode(color: .gray, size: CGSize(width: 75, height: 75))
    private let confirm = SKSpriteNode(color: .lightGray, size: CGSize(width: 75, height: 75))

    private var stage = 0

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        addChild(box)
        box.addChild(wizard)
        wizard.zPosition = 1
        back.zPosition = 1
        confirm.zPosition = 1
        back.position.x = -50
        confirm.position.x = 50
    }

    private func toggleStage(){

        if stage == 0 {

            wizard.removeFromParent()
            box.addChild(confirm)
            box.addChild(back)
            stage = 1
        }else{

            confirm.removeFromParent()
            back.removeFromParent()
            box.addChild(wizard)
            stage = 0
        }
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        if let touch = touches.first {

            let location = touch.location(in: self)

            if stage == 0 {

                if atPoint(location) == wizard {
                     toggleStage()
                }
            }else{
                if atPoint(location) == back {
                    print("Back button tapped")
                    toggleStage()
                }else if atPoint(location) == confirm {
                    print("Confirm button tapped")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, what you need to do is to swap sprites based on stage. Personally, I would make my own class called Menu, and Button or something like that and implement delegation when needed. But that's just me.